# Google Search Appliance Administration API

Tags: networking, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

We are using the GSA for our companies internal search and it has been configured as a secure URL i.e. https_colon_fwdSlash2_Myhostname.net:8443. I am trying to use the google search appliance Administration API to just connect to the GSA. I am using the Java version of the API and writting the programs on a different server within my companies network.

This is the Code I am trying to run

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;

 import com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient;
 import com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaEntry;
 import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

 public class GsaFirst {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException, ServiceException, IOException{

        System.out.println("The program started...");
        GsaClient myClient = new GsaClient("Myhostname.net", 8443, "username", "pwd1234");
        System.out.println("this is the error");
        //String addr = myClient.getAddress();
        //System.out.println(addr);

        GsaEntry myEntry = myClient.getEntry("config", "crawlURLs");
        System.out.println("Start URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("startURLs"));
        System.out.println("Follow URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("followURLs"));
        System.out.println("Do Not Crawl URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("doNotCrawlURLs"));

    }
```

}

The output I get is 
The program started...
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient.(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient.(Unknown Source)
    at com.gsa.GsaFirst.main(GsaFirst.java:14)

If someone can help me out or guide me what steps I would have to take to resolve this. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding this small snippet of code wich did the trick.

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;

  import com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaClient;
  import com.google.enterprise.apis.client.GsaEntry;
  import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

  public class GsaFirst {
  static {
    //for localhost testing only
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

        public boolean verify(String hostname,
                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
            if (hostname.equals("Myhostname.net")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
  public static void main(String args[]) throws MalformedURLException,   ServiceException, IOException{

    System.out.println("The program started...");
    GsaClient myClient = new GsaClient("Myhostname.net", 8443, "username", "pwd1234");
    System.out.println("this is the error");
    //String addr = myClient.getAddress();
    //System.out.println(addr);

    GsaEntry myEntry = myClient.getEntry("config", "crawlURLs");
    System.out.println("Start URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("startURLs"));
    System.out.println("Follow URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("followURLs"));
    System.out.println("Do Not Crawl URLs: " + myEntry.getGsaContent("doNotCrawlURLs"));

}
```